# Armar grafica de Chart.js desde JSON con AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Buen dia, he estado intentando llamar datos desde un archivo JSON a una grafica de chart.js mediante AJAX pero he fracasado en el intento jejeje

```
    {
    "inventario": [
        {
            "objeto1": [
                {
                    "BUY": [
                        {
                            "precio": 100,
                            "fecha": 1667737000
                        },
                        {
                            "precio": 150,
                            "fecha": 1667739000
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "SELL": [
                        {
                            "precio": 160,
                            "fecha": 1667737000
                        },
                        {
                            "precio": 200,
                            "fecha": 1667739000
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "objeto2": [
                {
                    "BUY": [
                        {
                            "precio": 100,
                            "fecha": 1667737000
                        },
                        {
                            "precio": 150,
                            "fecha": 1667739000
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "SELL": [
                        {
                            "precio": 160,
                            "fecha": 1667737000
                        },
                        {
                            "precio": 200,
                            "fecha": 1667739000
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }           
    ]
}
```

serian varias lineas en la grafica por que serian varios objetos que reflejar.
y bueno...
el sistema me pide que escriba mas detalles asi que escribo mas para que no sea mayormente codigo... pero en realidad no hay mucho mas que explicar para darme a entender...

no coloco mis intentos fallidos para que no se rian, esto lo sabria hacer pero con PHP pero necesito que sea con js y ajax

y este seria el JS de la grafica

```
    const $grafica = document.querySelector("#grafica");
    
    const etiquetas = ["fecha1", "fecha2", "fecha3", "fecha4"]
    
    const datosVentas2020 = {
        label: "Ventas por mes",
        data: [precio1, precio2, precio3, precio], 
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)', 
        borderColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)', 
        borderWidth: 1,
    };
new Chart($grafica, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: etiquetas,
        datasets: [
            datosVentas2020,
        ]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }],
        },
    }
});
```

me seria de gran ayuda aprender como lo harian ustedes Saludos

Comment: Tienes que poner el gráfico que quieres generar

Comment: una grafica de lineas... quiero recibir los datos en las variables etiquetas y data

Comment: No estimado así no. Debe colocar el gráfico al que quieres llegar, una imagen o boceto del resultado esperado. Tu problema es que no sabes agrupar los datos para dejarlos como te pide Chart js, mi problema es que no qué cosa hay que agrupar, porque no sé qué quieres mostrar.

Comment: alli en el json estan agrupados... obio esos datos son ejemplos pero fechas (etiquetas) van a lo horizontal y precios a lo vertical (data)... una linea por objeto  y una grafica para buy y otra para sell
el problema que tengo es como recibir esos datos desde el json al js

Comment: Entonces entendí todo mal, cual es el problema en cuestión: A) Graficar ese JSON usando CharJs o B) Como obtener ese JSON desde el servidor?